# Why is md-autocomplete setting my search-text as selected-item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

I have the following piece of html

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="SelectedSupervisor"
                                             md-search-text="SearchTerm"
                                             md-delay="3000"
                                             md-items="supervisor in MyFilter(SearchTerm)"
                                             md-min-length="4"
                                             placeholder="Search for Supervisor"
                                             md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
                                <md-item-template>
                                    <span class="item-title">
                                        <md-icon class="fa fa-user">
                                        </md-icon>

                                        <span>
                                            <strong>
                                                {{supervisor.Name}}
                                            </strong>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </md-item-template>
                            </md-autocomplete>
```

$scope.SearchTerm is simply a string value that I use.
However, whenever I click on one of the records of the autocomplete, which would be something like this:

```
$scope.SelectedSupervisor = 
{
    Id:0,
    Name:""
}
```

(Obviously, depending on the selected-item, the value would change for this variable). That value for example is set to $scope.SearchTerm, which of course makes my app crash since most functions on my app use $scope.SearchTerm itself as a string.

Why does the click on record set the value of $scope.SearchTerm  as that of the selected item?